# CS50 linked list implementation using recursion

Tags: c, cs50

I was trying to implement a linked list by recursion, as I am weak at it.

The doubt is in recursion itself.
Say I have `*temp` (say 0x1) `= rec_function();` --- call 1
in the next call if the address in `temp` change from `0x1` to `0x2` (say), will the output of call 1 be stored in `0x1` or `0x2`?

`temp` is a global variable.

Code(if someone wants to go through it)

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
typedef struct node{
char* data ;
struct node* ptr ;

}node;
node* list = NULL ;
node* temp = NULL ;

node* create_stacked_list(int argc ,char* argv[]){
int i = 0 ;
if(argc == 2 ){
temp = malloc(sizeof(node)) ;
list = temp ;
(*list).ptr = NULL ;
(*list).data = argv[1] ;
return list ;
}
else{
temp = malloc(sizeof(node)) ;
(*temp).data = argv[argc -1 ] ;
argv[argc - 1 ] = NULL ;
argc-- ;
if(i==0) {list = temp ;}

temp -> ptr = create_stacked_list(argc ,argv);
printf("line28");
//list = temp ;
return list ;
}
i++;

} ;


int main(int argc , char * argv[]){
//format :elements in list as a stack ;
//create the list ;

list = create_stacked_list(argc,argv) ;
node* ptr = (*list).ptr ;
while ( ptr != NULL ) {
printf("%s\n" , (*(ptr)).data);
printf("%p \n " , ptr );
ptr = (*ptr).ptr;

}









}
```

new code for doubly linked lists :

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stddef.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
//define a node
typedef struct dllnode{
    int val ;
    struct dllnode* prev ;
    struct dllnode* next ;

}node;
//globally declare head of list
node* list = NULL ;


//create the first node
node* first_node(int val){
    list = malloc(sizeof(node));
    (*list).prev = NULL ;
    (*list).next = NULL ;
    (*list).val = val ;
    return list ;

}

//keep adding the other nodes
node* add_node(int val){
    node* temp = malloc(sizeof(node));
    (*temp).next = list ;
    (*list).prev = temp ;
    (*temp).val = val ;
    (*temp).prev = NULL ;
    list = temp ;
    
    return list ;

}
//function to print out the list
void print_out(node* node){
    while((*node).next != NULL){
        printf("%i \n" , (*node).val) ;
        node = (*node).next ;





    }
    printf("%i \n", (*node).val);



}
//function to delete an element from the list 
void delete( node* node  , int val ){
    while(node->val != val){
        node = node->next ;
    }
    
    
    
    if(node->val == val){
        (*(node->next)).prev = node->prev ;
        (*(node->prev)).next = node->next ;
        node->prev = NULL ;
        node->next = NULL ;
        
    }
    
    
}





//main function
int main(void) {

    int i = 1;
    printf("Enter element number %i : " , i) ;
    int val = 0 ;
    scanf("%i" , &val) ;
    first_node(val);
    i++;
    while(val != 314){
        printf("Enter element number %i : " , i) ;
        scanf("%i" , &val) ;
        if(val == 314){
            break;
        }
        add_node(val);
        i++;
    }
    
    print_out(list);
    int del ;
    printf("delete the middle number : ");
    scanf("%i" ,&del);
    delete(list ,del);
    print_out(list);




}
```

I know that it still has a lot of limitations but it feels nice.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Poor readability is a source of many errors. Especially for beginners. You should apply proper indentation to your code. Indentation should reflect logical structure of your code.

Comment: "will the output of call 1 be stored in 0x1 or 0x2?" that is a perfect occasion to learn how to debug your code. Run the program in your debugger and watch how the variables change while you step through your instructions.

Comment: This code is absolutely unreadable, please learn how to properly format your code!

Comment: Somewhat OT: you don't need recursion here. Are you required to use recursion?

Comment: @Somewhat OT , no we arent , as I mentioned I am weak at it , so I wanted to try it this way .

Comment: @Marco yeah my friends keep saying that :)

Comment: @saket If you start to use proper formatting, they will probably stop saying that.

Comment: @Chris true , i will eventully get there , atleast thats what i hope

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must first learn to make readable code, for others but also for your own sake.  Proper indentation and spacing is key to make the program structure more visible, and also make problems in the code more obvious.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node {
    char *data;
    struct node *ptr;
} node;

node *list = NULL;
node *temp = NULL;

node *create_stacked_list(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int i = 0;
    if (argc == 2) {
        temp = malloc(sizeof(node));
        list = temp;
        (*list).ptr = NULL;
        (*list).data = argv[1];
        return list;
    } else {
        temp = malloc(sizeof(node));
        (*temp).data = argv[argc - 1];
        argv[argc - 1] = NULL;
        argc--;
        if (i == 0) {
            list = temp;
        }
        temp->ptr = create_stacked_list(argc, argv);
        printf("line28");
        //list = temp;
        return list;
    }
    i++;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    //format :elements in list as a stack;
    //create the list;

    list = create_stacked_list(argc, argv);
    node *ptr = (*list).ptr;
    while (ptr != NULL) {
        printf("%s\n", (*(ptr)).data);
        printf("%p \n ", ptr);
        ptr = (*ptr).ptr;
    }
}
```

Using short informative names for variables and structure members  with helps readability too: `ptr` should be `next` in the `node` structure.

Using global variables is not a good idea. In you example, there is no need for global variables:  `create_stacked_list` returns a pointer to the allocated head node, and `temp` is only used in that function.

It is also more readable to use the pointer syntax `ptr->data` instead of the equivalent but cumbersome `(*ptr).data`.

Here is an improved version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node {
    char *data;
    struct node *next;
} node;

node *create_stacked_list(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    node *list = NULL;
    node *temp = NULL;

    int i = 0;
    if (argc == 2) {
        temp = malloc(sizeof(node));
        list = temp;
        list->ptr = NULL;
        list->data = argv[1];
        return list;
    } else {
        node *temp = malloc(sizeof(node));
        temp->data = argv[argc - 1];
        argv[argc - 1] = NULL;
        argc--;
        if (i == 0) {
            list = temp;
        }
        temp->next = create_stacked_list(argc, argv);
        return list;
    }
    i++;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    //format :elements in list as a stack;
    //create the list;

    node *list = create_stacked_list(argc, argv);
    node *ptr = list->next;
    while (ptr != NULL) {
        printf("%s\n", ptr->data);
        printf("%p\n", ptr);
        ptr = ptr->next;
    }
}
```

Regarding recursion, the principle is to break the task into an elementary one, such as allocating a list node, and using a recursive call to the same function for a shorter task. A simple test prevents infinite recursion for the simplest task.

In your case, the simplest task is returning `NULL` for a zero length array.

Here is a modified version of the recursive function:

```
node *create_stacked_list(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (argc == 0) {
        return NULL;
    } else {
        node *list = malloc(sizeof(node));
        // Use the first array element for this node
        list->data = argv[0];
        // Create a list with the remaining elements in the array
        //   and store the pointer into the `next` member.
        // There are `argc - 1` remaining elements
        //   `argv + 1`, or equivalently `&argv[1]` is a pointer to
        //   the next element in the array
        list->next = create_stacked_list(argc - 1, argv + 1);
        return list;
    }
}
```

The same recursive approach can be used to free the list:

```
void free_stacked_list(node *list) {
    if (list) {
        free_stacked_list(list->next);
        free(list);
    }
}
```

The `main` function should also be modified so the full list is displayed and freed:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    // create the list
    node *list = create_stacked_list(argc, argv);
    // print the list
    for (node *ptr = list; ptr != NULL; ptr = ptr->next) {
        printf("%p: %s\n", (void *)ptr, ptr->data);
    }
    free_stacked_list(list);
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the final program you can study:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node {
    char *data;
    struct node *next;
} node;

node *create_stacked_list(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (argc == 0) {
        return NULL;
    } else {
        node *list = malloc(sizeof(node));
        // Use the first array element for this node
        list->data = argv[0];
        // Create a list with the remaining elements in the array
        //   and store the pointer into the `next` member.
        // There are `argc - 1` remaining elements
        //   `argv + 1`, or equivalently `&argv[1]` is a pointer to
        //   the next element in the array
        list->next = create_stacked_list(argc - 1, argv + 1);
        return list;
    }
}

void free_stacked_list(node *list) {
    if (list) {
        free_stacked_list(list->next);
        free(list);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    // create the list
    node *list = create_stacked_list(argc, argv);
    // print the list
    for (node *ptr = list; ptr != NULL; ptr = ptr->next) {
        printf("%p: %s\n", (void *)ptr, ptr->data);
    }
    free_stacked_list(list);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: can you explain what is meaning of argv +1 here?
 ```list->next = create_stacked_list(argc - 1, argv + 1)```
Is it same as argv[previous number +1 ] ?

Comment: And if that is so , dont i need to change the input parameters of the function?

Comment: `argv + 1` advances the `argv` pointer to the next element in the array. If there is no such element the resulting pointer must not be dereferenced. Which won't happen because `argc - 1` is `0` in that case.

Comment: @Marco why is everyone disliking the question? I was genuinely confused about the order in which assignment operator works.

Comment: oh , its because of readibility of code

Comment: Yes, that is definitely one of the reasons. It shows lack of effort which is generally disliked on this site. People take their free time to help you (for free) so you should make them helping you as easy as possible.

Comment: @Marco I am sorry about that , honeslty I wasnt going to submit the code itself as I though no one would want to read it(I see your point) , my doubt was just in that assignment thing

Comment: @saket: Every programmer started as a beginner. If you work hard and learn from others, you will make progress and enjoy writing code that does more complex things and solve real problems.  There is no shame in asking questions, no matter how simple or awkward, so keep learning something new and interesting every day.

Comment: @chqrlie thank you for the answer , also one funny thing I was able to access my username on codespace by poking around with memory

Comment: @saket Yes, don't feel discouraged to ask questions here on stackoverflow. Just make sure to put effort into your questions and make sure that you've done your research (e.g. has this question been asked before). On a more personal note, stackoverflow is known to be hostile to beginners but that shouldn't discourage you from learning how to ask proper questions (here on stackoverflow that is) and how to program. As chqrlie said, everyone started out as a beginner. Happy coding!

Comment: @Marco and chqrlie thanks to you people I learnt double linked lists today. I have edited the question, with the new code, hopefully with more readability.